# How to extract article contents from websites with different layouts

Tags: python, html-parsing

I have a list of 1,000 URLs of articles published by different agencies, and of course each has its own HTML layout.
I am writing a python code to extract ONLY the article body from each URL. Can this be done by **only looking at the < p>< /p> Paragraph tags**?
Will I be missing some content? or including irrelevant content by this approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some articles you will be missing content, and for others you will include irrelevant content. There is really no way to grab just the article body from a URL since each site layout will likely vary significantly.

One thing you could try is grabbing text contained in multiple consecutive p tags inside the body tag, but there is still no guarantee you will get just the body of the article.

It would be a lot easier if you broke the list of URLs into a list for each distinct site, that would you could define what the article body is case by case.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, it's highly unlikely you can get ONLY article content targeting `<p></p>` tags. You WILL get a lot of unnecessary content that will take a ton of effort to filter through, guaranteed.

Try to find an RSS feed for these websites. That will make scraping target data much easier than parsing an entire HTML page.